# Program conversion to process

Tags: linux, process, operating-system

I am practicing Linux programming in c language. But I am little curious about how a program becomes a process what are the major steps involved in program becoming a process?

Comment: It's open-source.  Why not examine the process loader?

Answer (score 0):

That depends upon the operating system. I am aware of two models.

1. The process is created when the user logs into the system. The system sets up a command interpreter that runs in the background of the process. One tells the command interpreter to run a program. This loads the program and starts executing. When the program exits, control returns to the command interpreter and the same process can run another program.
2. A process is always a clone of another process (the unix method). Usually the starting point is a shell. You tell the shell to run a program. The shell makes a copy of itself, creating a new process. Then it loads the program you want to run, replacing the shell. When that program finishes, the process dies.

Answer (score 0):

When you type a command on shell, it creates new identical process by fork(), then one of exec functions are called to detach this process so that newly created process can execute its own code. In this exec function, code and data of your program are loaded into memory from binary file(on linux ELF) stored on hard disk.